# Why relational tables with doctrine are not creating?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I hope you are having a nice day,

I'm using Symfony 3 and my question is:

I have 5 entities:

·Cancion
·Duracion
·Genero
·Mood
·Tempo

and I wanna have relations between them so I declared a class Cancion.php defining the relational properties with its respective annotations:

```
...
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Genero", inversedBy="canciones")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="canciones_generos",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cancion_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="genero_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $generos;

/*
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Mood", inversedBy="canciones")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="canciones_moods",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cancion_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mood_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $moods;

/*
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tempo", inversedBy="canciones")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="canciones_tempos",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cancion_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tempo_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $tempos;

/*
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Duracion", inversedBy="canciones")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="canciones_duraciones",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cancion_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="duracion_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $duracion;

public function __construct() {
    $this->generos = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->moods= new ArrayCollection();
    $this->tempos= new ArrayCollection();
    $this->duracion= new ArrayCollection();
}
```

and the other classes are like this (for example Duracion.php):

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Cancion", mappedBy="duracion")
 */
private $canciones;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->canciones = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The problem is when I execute the command to update the scheme it just create 5 (corresponding to each entity) tables but not the relational tables:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force;php bin/console doctrine:database:create;php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

In all entities I'm using:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

What I'm doing wrong, how can I have the relational tables?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any old mapping files under Resources/config/doctrine.

Comment: Hi @Cerad , I don't have even a config directory in Resources, it just have a  views directory.
And in the bundle Resource/config directory I only have a services.yml file, which doesn't have content.

Comment: you can try validating the schema  ``php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`` , few other things to look out for, clear doctrine metadata cache , make sure the class is marked as Entity using appropriate annotations.

Comment: Hi @VamsiKrishnaB I've used php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate , and i have this on return, I don't understand why my entity is wrong, do you see something else I don't?:
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'GaryBundle\Entity\Duracion' mapping is invalid:
* The association GaryBundle\Entity\Duracion#canciones refers to the owning side field GaryBundle\Entity\Cancion#duracion which does not exist.
.... and the same with other entities. And finally shows:
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

Comment: My fault, I had a typo mistake, I used /* instead /** thats why it doesn't work.